# Is there any script or tool to Map gene SNP positions to genome coordinates

Tags: command-line, bash

Is there any script or tool to Map gene SNP positions to genome coordinates, for example

> CHROM     POS     ID    REF    ALT
>
> 1            **60**             .       A        T

60 is snp position in genes not chr 1

now i want to find position of A in chr1, mean genomic position, of variant position in chromosomes not with in gene

for example gene start at 10000 position of chr1 , than inplace of 60 come 10060 mean genomic position of this variant. Please have any idea about it ???

Comment: This sounds highly specialized and I suggest a google search. Are you mapping human or other genes / chromosomes ? If human, contact the human genome project.