# Does Linux (Ubuntu) have a tool to handle a full gene test result like a CRAM file?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am downloading a 50Gb CRAM file and it's associated index file. Rather than go online all the time to the tester front end , is there a program for Linux that can handle it.  Ditto for ancestry results.

Comment: not quite the same as here .https://askubuntu.com/questions/949144/is-there-any-script-or-tool-to-map-gene-snp-positions-to-genome-coordinates

Comment: Read `man apt-cache`. Try `apt-cache search gene` and`apt-cache search CRAM`, `apt-cache search ancestry.

Comment: @waltinator, thanks for that hidden trick. I did get too many results but if I do 'apt-cache search CRAM | grep CRAM' that tidied it up. alternatively I could -v negation for all the unwanted items. sam and sam-gui seems to be the thing I am looking for.

Comment: though apt install of those gives unable to locate package , but it gives me a tip. a search 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+ancestry+tools+CRAM&t=ffab&ia=web' gives me samtools and  https://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-fasta.html

Comment: and then there is a bundle which includes a gui and sam . https://brb.nci.nih.gov/seqtools/index.html . requires registration but that went through immediately to download. If it works I will post it as an answer.